# ORACLE 11g DB Response slow with CAKEPHP on AMAZON

Tags: php, oracle11g, wamp, cakephp-1.3, oci8

We have a Cakephp 1.3 application that is connected with ORACLE 11g Database ,

First it was hosted on our in house server there was no problem , but as we moved to AWS , database is giving slow response some time , some time it is very fast .

Configuration is 32 GB RAM,
Database and PHP Application is on same server , there can be any network issue for DB Connection .

What can be the Possible problems.

I have created test Page linked below , and code is :

```
<?php // Connects to the XE service (i.e. database) on the "localhost"     machine
//echo "there"; die;
$conn = oci_connect('hrpay', 'hrpay', 'localhost/orcl');
if (!$conn) {
$e = oci_error();
trigger_error(htmlentities($e['message'], ENT_QUOTES), E_USER_ERROR);} 
//die('here');
$stid = oci_parse($conn, 'SELECT * FROM makess.mst_company');
oci_execute($stid);
echo "<table border='1'>\n";
while ($row = oci_fetch_array($stid, OCI_ASSOC+OCI_RETURN_NULLS)) {
echo "<tr>\n";
foreach ($row as $item) {
    echo "    <td>" . ($item !== null ? htmlentities($item,     ENT_QUOTES) : "&nbsp;") . "</td>\n";
}
echo "</tr>\n";}
echo "</table>\n";?>
```

It is dynamically very slow .

Comment: You don't have oracle db, you only have oracle xe. In addition can you quantify what slow means?

Comment: The problem can be related to your `weblogic-server` that communicates your local `DB-services` to your browser services. If weblogic lags so would your oracle service which communicates over browser. @steve by `oracle db` do you mean `Oracle-11G Standard Edition`?